# getting average of CPU utilization from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

is there a way to get the CPU utilization average result in specific timing from kibana graph instead of calculating it by myself ?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

You can [monitor your cluster](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/monitor-elasticsearch-cluster.html) with [Metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/index.html).
Although it will only give you the system load.
But you have no more details.

Then again there are modules such as the [Linux](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-metricset-linux-pressure.html) one, which offer more information on the cpu usage.

If none of those offer what you need you might want to roll out your own solution ^^

Or wait for an update of someone with better knowledge.